# MS-Access, Using input masks but with limited characters

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've looked this up, and can't really find the answer, but is it possible to say have a input Mask that only accepts Limited characters?

Example

~ ~ ~ ~

In the four slots above, I would like Slot 1 to only be a 1 (which I know I can set) Slot 2 to only accept A-S & 1-9 , Slot 3 to accept a-c and the fourth slot can be anything.

so something like 1AC9 would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an input mask in conjunction with a validation rule:

```
Like "1[A-S1-9][a-c]?"
```

This will not force an upper case in slot 2, but an input mask will:

```
 \1>A<L&;0
```